# Reading parquet files from gs or s3a fails with ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

Tags: apache-flink, parquet, avro

I'm using Flink 1.16.0 with Kotlin to read and process (snappy-compressed) parquet files that were generated by Spark, and I keep running into `ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration`. The files are on Google Cloud Storage/`gs://`, but the problem replicates with MiniO and `s3a://`.

My Jobs use the Table API to read the parquets, convert the table to a stream and then perform some stream processing into a (Kotlin) data class, which is persisted with `AvroParquetWriters`. A minimal version:

```kotlin
val query = """
    CREATE TABLE data (letter STRING, timedigit BIGINT) WITH (
        'connector' = 'filesystem',
        'path' = '${inputPath}',
        'format' = 'parquet'
    )
    """

tableEnv.executeSql(query)

val dataTable = tableEnv.from("data")

val parquetSink = FileSink
    .forBulkFormat(Path(outputPath), AvroParquetWriters.forReflectRecord(Data::class.java))
    .build()

tableEnv
    .toDataStream(dataTable)
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
        WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks<Row>().withTimestampAssigner { row, _ -> row.getFieldAs("timedigit") }
    )
    .map { row -> Data(row.getFieldAs("timedigit"), row.getFieldAs("letter")) }
    .sinkTo(parquetSink)

env.execute("Read from and write to parquet")
```

My `build.gradle` is [constructed as instructed in the Flink docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/configuration/overview/) and includes the [necessary dependencies for parquet](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/connectors/datastream/formats/parquet/):

```
dependencies {  
    implementation "org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java:${flinkVersion}"  
    implementation "org.apache.flink:flink-table-api-java:${flinkVersion}"  
    implementation "org.apache.flink:flink-table-api-java-bridge:${flinkVersion}"  
    implementation "org.apache.flink:flink-clients:${flinkVersion}"  
    implementation "org.apache.flink:flink-connector-files:${flinkVersion}"  

    flinkShadowJar "org.apache.flink:flink-parquet:${flinkVersion}"  
    flinkShadowJar("org.apache.parquet:parquet-avro:1.12.2") {  
        exclude group: "org.apache.hadoop", module: "hadoop-client"  
        exclude group: "it.unimi.dsi", module: "fastutil"  
    }    flinkShadowJar ("org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.1.8.4") {  
        exclude group: "org.osgi", module: "core"  
    }  

    runtimeOnly "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:${log4jVersion}"  
    runtimeOnly "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:${log4jVersion}"  
    runtimeOnly "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:${log4jVersion}"  
}
```

I'm running the Job with a Docker image on Kubernetes "native" in [application mode](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/resource-providers/native_kubernetes/#application-mode). This is the docker file for the `s3a` case, where I'm providing the [s3 hadoop plugin in the `plugins` directory](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/deployment/filesystems/s3/):

```
# PART 1 - Build jar via gradle  
FROM gradle:7.5.1-jdk11 AS gradle
WORKDIR /usr/src/app  
COPY build.gradle build.gradle  
COPY settings.gradle settings.gradle  
COPY src src    
RUN gradle clean installShadowDist  

# Part 2 - Create flink container with jar  
FROM flink:1.16.0-java11    
ARG kotlinVersion=1.7.21  
ARG flinkVersion=1.16.0  
USER flink  

## Provide Kotlin jar  
RUN wget -P $FLINK_HOME/lib https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/${kotlinVersion}/kotlin-stdlib-${kotlinVersion}.jar  
  
## Provide Job jar  
RUN mkdir -p $FLINK_HOME/usrlib  
COPY --from=gradle /usr/src/app/build/libs/flink-parquet-batch-demo-1.0-all.jar $FLINK_HOME/usrlib/flink-parquet-batch-demo.jar  
  
## Provide S3 plugin  
RUN mkdir -p $FLINK_HOME/plugins/s3-fs-hadoop  
RUN cp $FLINK_HOME/opt/flink-s3-fs-hadoop-${flinkVersion}.jar $FLINK_HOME/plugins/s3-fs-hadoop/
```

I'm using the same image to launch the job from within Kubernetes, i.e. I create a Pod based on this image, ssh into it and launch the job via

```bash
./bin/flink run-application \  
--target kubernetes-application --class demo.Job \  
-Dkubernetes.cluster-id=flink-application-cluster \  
-Dkubernetes.container.image=flink-custom:latest \  
-Dkubernetes.service-account=flink-service-account \  
-Dparallelism.default=2 \  
-Dexecution.runtime-mode=BATCH \  
-Ds3.endpoint=http://172.17.0.4:9000 \  
-Ds3.path-style=true \  
-Ds3.access-key=minioadmin \  
-Ds3.secret-key=minioadmin \  
local:///opt/flink/usrlib/flink-parquet-batch-demo.jar \  
--input_path s3a://data/parquet-data/ \  
--output_path s3a://data/output-data/
```

#### What I've tried

Things I've tried that unfortunately lead to the same `ClassNotFoundException`:

- Switched the entire project to maven
- Job submission via the Flink kubernetes operator (instead of the scripts that ship with Flink)
- Job submission via session mode (instead of application mode)
- Running everything in Docker instead of k8s
- Removed the `parquet-avro` dependency
- Removed the `snappy-java` dependency
- Left out the `gs` / `s3a` plugins
- Included `org.apache.flink:flink-hadoop-compatibility_2.12` via `flinkShadowJar`
- included `org.apache.flink:flink-sql-parquet:1.16.0` via `flinkShadowJar`

When I include either `hadoop-core` or `hadoop-client` via `flinkShadowJar`, the exception disappears and the taskmanagers launch, but I'm getting a `org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "s3a"` / `No FileSystem for scheme "gs"`. Also, to my understanding [adding any Hadoop dependencies is discouraged](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/configuration/advanced/#hadoop-dependencies).

I've committed a minimal project at https://github.com/mcpeanutbutter/Flink-parquet-batch-demo that includes the full log and stacktrace (`output.log`).

Comment: My initial thought was "I've seen something similar like this" and remember ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-29729 - Could that be the issue for you too?

Comment: Thank you @martijn, yes, this might be strongly related! If the contents of `flink-conf.yaml` are ignored when the parquet reader is created, it might not be able to get a Hadoop conf at all. I wonder, however, if the PR referenced in the ticket would solve my issue entirely, since as far as I can tell, the "vanilla" `flink-conf.yaml` doesn't even include any Hadoop configuration keys.